# Admin java applets in Oracle Webcenter content WCC does not opens

Tags: java, security, oracle11g, applet, webcenter

Admin java applets in Oracle Webcenter content WCC does not opens.

ERROR: Application blocked by security.

I know its java version issue. Java version installed is Java 8 update 20.

I have also added application URL in Java exception list but no success.
Any permanent soln is much appreciated.

I would also like to know in which exact java version does Java applets opens correctly?
P.S- I'm at client side and cannot install any other Java version.

Answer (score 2):

As my previous Project,  Java Version 6 will work.   7 or 8 won't work for my 11.1.1.6 version wcc.

And also please be aware of the 32bit version or 64 bit version of jdk/jre

It is quite normal that you have a 64bit OS with 32bit browser, in this way you need to install 32bit JDK/JRE 6 to make the applet work.

If you want a specific version, it should be Java SE Development Kit 6u27. However, should also work as long as it falls in java 6 category.

Alternatively, you can login to the server, and launch the applet through the command line.  It should be inside cs/bin/ComponentManager.. etc

Answer (score 1):

Digitally sign the applets.  That is most of the solution to getting them to open in modern JREs.